# Is it possible to save .xlsx as read-only using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

It feels like there should be a way to save a .xlsx file as read-only using pandas' `to_excel` function or the `XLSXwriter` module.

I have looked at both documentations without luck.

`to_excel`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandasdocs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

`XLSXwriter`: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html

Is there another way to achieve this within pandas?

Comment: By read only - do you mean the readonly file or the protected cells in the report?

Comment: the entire file

Comment: @p_sutherland .. Have you got any solution .. ? I am also having same prob

Comment: I never did find a way to do it in pandas itself :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with Pandas when using xlsxwriter as the engine:

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_read_only.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")

# Set the Excel output file as "Read-only Recommended".
writer.book.read_only_recommended()

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Output when opening file:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it can be done with pandas but you can set it to read only after you create it.

```
import os
from stat import S_IREAD, S_IRGRP, S_IROTH
os.chmod(filename, S_IREAD|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH)
```

Comment: Yes -- that's likely what I will do. I am interested if there is a way to do it in pandas itself

Comment: I don't think this will do it. Locks on an excel need to be set within the file, not on the flags?

Answer (score 2):

Still, if you want to use `XLSXwriter`

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
...
book = Workbook('file/path')
sheet = book.add_worksheet('worksheet_name')

# Add separate format for unlocked cells
unlocked = book.add_format({'locked': 0})
# Protect all cells in your sheet by default
sheet.protect()
...
# Write cell, locked by default
sheet.write(row_number, column_number, data)
# Write another cell, unlock it
sheet.write(row_number, column_number, data, unlocked)
...
book.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Yaroslav, but I am interested in making the workbook itself read-only, no just specific cells or sheets.

Comment: Actually, I've to store a spark dataframe in a excel file format with few column as a read only nature? Can you guide me regarding the same?

Answer (score 2):

Similar answer to @Alex-Zisman, but for Windows:

```
import win32con, win32api, os

file_path = 'path/to/file.xlsx'
win32api.SetFileAttributes(file_path, win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting another way to do it. I am not going to accept the answer for the same reason I did not accept @Alex Zisman's answer... I am specifically looking for a solution within pandas

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below guidelines. I think it might give answer of your question:

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

workbook.read_only_recommended()

workbook.close()

**read_only_recommended()**- This method can be used to set the Excel “Read-only Recommended” option that is available when saving a file. This presents the user of the file with an option to open it in “read-only” mode. This means that any changes to the file can’t be saved back to the same file and must be saved to a new file.